# Why does selecting new instances only construct on enumeration?

Tags: c#, linq

Why does the following create instances every time you loop through the IEnumerable instead of during the initial Select?

```
this.bars = this.values.Select(x => new Bar(x));
```

I would expect that to loop through the values, selecting a new Bar then and there, but having tested it it creates no instances at that moment and instead creates new instances every time you loop through it.

```
    private IEnumerable<Bar> bars;
```

The bars field is declared as an IEnuermable, so I don't understand how it could be holding any kind of function or closure.

- Is this expected behaviour, and if so why?
- How would I do this with Linq but create one set of new instances then and there?

---

Full source of Console test app:

```
namespace LINQ_Test
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Linq;

    public class Bar
    {
        private int value;

        public Bar(int value)
        {
            this.value = value;
            Debug.WriteLine("CTOR: " + value);
        }
    }

    public class Foo
    {
        private IEnumerable<Bar> bars;
        private IEnumerable<int> values = new int[] { 0, 1234, -1 };

        public void LoopValues()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Looping through bars 3 times:");
            for (int loop = 0; loop < 3; loop++)
            {
                foreach (Bar bar in this.bars)
                {
                }
                Debug.WriteLine("   (next loop)");
            }
            Debug.WriteLine("-\n");
        }

        public void SetupValues()
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Settings up bars:");
            this.bars = this.values.Select(x => new Bar(x));
            Debug.WriteLine("-\n");
        }
    }

    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Foo foo = new Foo();
            foo.SetupValues();
            foo.LoopValues();
        }
    }
}
```

App Output:

```
Settings up bars:
-

Looping through bars 3 times:
CTOR: 0
CTOR: 1234
CTOR: -1
   (next loop)
CTOR: 0
CTOR: 1234
CTOR: -1
   (next loop)
CTOR: 0
CTOR: 1234
CTOR: -1
   (next loop)
-
```

Comment: Yes, it's expected behavior. You can enumerate it once using `this.values.Select(x => new Bar(x)).ToList();` I think ReSharper even tells you in cases like this that there is `Possible Multiple Enumeration of IEnumerable`.

Comment: This is the expected behavior, google Linq Lazy Evaluation.

Comment: this has to be a FAQ by now...

Comment: Thanks - Oh, OK, I think I've got it - so the select returns an enumerator that contains the requested function, and ToList() runs through and yields the results out?

Comment: Linq statement are queries like a database query.  The execution doesn't always get performed like an in-line instruction.  The query get stored in memory and get executed when the output variable is used later in the code.

Comment: @Octopoid yes; your code eventually translates into a call to `GetEnumerator` followed by `MoveNext` calls; the code in your lamba doesn't run until `MoveNext` is called.

Comment: Got it - thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is expected behavior, and documented in the [`IEnumerable#Select` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx). From that link:

> This method is implemented by using deferred execution. The immediate return value is an object that stores all the information that is required to perform the action. The query represented by this method is not executed until the object is enumerated either by calling its `GetEnumerator` method directly or by using `foreach` in Visual C# or `For Each` in Visual Basic.

If you want it done immediately, enumerate it immediately, perhaps with [`ToList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Ah, there it is! I understand whats going on now, thanks for that.